# Shortest Path No route found QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3

I am using shortest path point to point and I have found the following problem:

I am using a road network which includes some roads that have one way and others are bidirectional.  My origin and destination points are not in the network but they are near the network.

If I run the shortest path algorithm without specifying a road direction I get the shortest path between the points, but if I define the one way roads, I do not get a result.

The problem seems to be that the shortest path algorithm first looks for the shortest distance between the points and the road network and then runs the algorithm using that information.  If the shortest distance between the points and the road network lies on a one way road that is not reachable then it gives a not path found error, even if there is a reachable road within the network only a few meters away.

Is there a way to modify the algorithm to search for other points? (Something like, if no route is find, search for the second closest point between the road network and the origin destination points and try again)

Comment: I have a similar problem and wondered if you came up with a solution for your problem. Thank you very much.